# How to get python3 kernel on my jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I check available kernel's on my anaconda it shows python3. I opened Jupyter notebook with python3 notebook. But then it won't show python3 in the place of kernel. And that's why I can't run any of my code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click "kernel" in the menu, choose "Change kernel" and select "Python 3".

Comment: On clicking kernel no "Python 3 " kernel is showing.

Comment: Do you install python3 on your computer?